# SOLIDITY - How to use pop() on 2D arrays with shifting method

Tags: solidity, remix

I've been trying to create a pop() function where if I remove any element from a 2D array, it changes down to the last element (Yes, I know it would waste a lot of gas, but it's just for learning purposes)

for instance:
`uint [][] xd = [2,3][5,4,6][7,8,9]`, suppose I want to get rid of element 2 in array 1, how can I make a change? where 6 now occupies the space of 4, then 7 occupies the space of 6, and so on? And thus, remove the last element because of the last duplicating element..

Like this code, which works fine for 1D arrays:

```
array[i]=Free.OneDimension[i+1];
```